# Can the DOM be a DAG or must it remain a tree?

Tags: javascript, dom

It's puzzling. I'm expecting that just googling for the question in
the subject line would provide a clear answer, but since not even a hint of
an answer comes up, I'm asking.

The code below uses D3 for convenience, but the question is about the
DOM. Feel free to use the (lesser IMHO) jquery or (the far-lesser)
barebone DOM manipulation code, if you prefer, to answer.

A number of DIVs appear on the left (). While hovering one of the DIVs
is magnified on the right ().

```js
function magnify(i) {
    return function() {
        var right = d3.select("right");
        right.selectAll("*").remove();
        right.append("magunit")
             .html("<h2>" + i + "</h2>");
    }
}
for(i=0; i<256; i++) {
    var unit = d3.select("left").append("unit")
                 .on("mouseenter",magnify(i));
    unit.html("<h2>" + i + "</h2>");
}
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; }
mycontainer { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; flex-flow: row; }
left { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; flex: 1; overflow-y: auto;}
right { display: flex; flex-flow: row; flex: 1; }
unit { flex: 1 1 auto; width: 80px; height: 60px; border: solid 1px black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <mycontainer><left></left><right></right></mycontainer>
```

Is it necessary to recreate each DIV? What does the standard say about
pointing to an existing DIV from two leaves, effectively making the
DOM a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) rather than a tree?

[image: can-the-dom-be-a-dag]

**Clarification, in reply to Kaiido's comment**

I'm using a `<unit>` here in place of something arbitrarily complex to keep the code brief. The point would be to move pointers rather than constantly recreate the (arbitrarily complex) unit structures. Hence "just change the text inside `<h2>`" doesn't cut it, but "switch to SVG and utilize `<use>`" is right on.

**Relevant**

- [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. By `DAG` I suppose you mean directed acyclic graph. But I can't see how that connects with the body of your question.

Comment: @vlaz I added a figure for clarity.

Comment: if you're asking if the same element can be the child of multiple elements (e.g. one div is a child of two divs who are themselves siblings, for example), then the simple answer is No. Think about it - if you had to write the HTML by hand, how would you write that using markup? HTML is fundamentally a written markup language, and the DOM is just a way of traversing it.

Comment: @ADyson Good. But we're not writing the DOM by hand. Are we still constrained with the HTMLs that can be written by hand (and can you back that up with a reference or another reasoning)?

Comment: OK, I see. So it's indeed an element having multiple parents. Yeah, what @ADyson says is entirely on point - you cannot define that structure in HTML. Nor in XML for that matter. Unless you start linking objects by id or something but fundamentally we aren't talking about this here but rather them being *nested*.

Comment: From which level are we talking about? In the markup? Then SVG has the [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) element, which allows to represent an other element in the tree. Technically (for the UA only), the linked DocumentFragment is cloned though (in the ShadowDOM), so it is actually not the same Element, but a clone, and for the DOM, the SVGUseElement is void. And for your example, no you don't have to recreate each Element, you could very well just change their inner textNodes textContent.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're asking whether the same element can be the child of multiple elements (e.g. one div is a child of two divs who are themselves siblings, for example), then the simple answer is No.

Think about it - if you had to write the HTML by hand, how would you write that using markup? HTML is fundamentally a written markup language, and the DOM is just a way of representing a HTML document programmatically so that scripts can manipulate it.

We are constrained by that, because whatever is within the DOM must be expressible as valid HTML, and vice-versa. Ultimately the browser parses the HTML document in order to know what to display. The structure of the document is (must be) strictly a tree because in HTML (and XML) child elements are created by placing them within their parent element (i.e. nesting). There is no way to express a multi-parent relationship using this format.

If we were designing the web again today we might do it differently, but this is part of the legacy we've got from nearly 30 years ago - when JavaScript wasn't even a thing.

If you want a general reference about the relationship between the DOM and HTML documents, I would recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/… to begin with.

See also  https://w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-LS-20040407/load-save.html . This the W3C spec describing how a DOM object must be serialisable both from and to XML (of which HTML is, of course, a specific variety). If it's serialisable to XML, then it must be representable as a hierarchical tree, because that's what XML requires.

And https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#nodes is the current living standard, describing how the DOM is a hierarchical tree of nodes.

Comment: Internally the browser takes HTML (as well as CSS and JS) and converts it to a DOM, not the other way around. But you're missing the point of my question. I'm not debating whether it's a good idea one way or the other. I'm not lamenting that we should design anything again. I'm merely asking: Is an implementation of a DAG feasible? Will, for example, (the better) browsers know how to garbage-collect in the presence of multiple in-pointers?

Comment: I'm not debating it either, I'm trying to add some context. I didn't miss the point of your question at all - you asked if it was possible, I answered that in the first paragraph - no.

Comment: "Internally the browser takes HTML (as well as CSS and JS) and converts it to a DOM, not the other way around. "...yes, but then it must convert it back again in order to write it back into the HTML document. If you changed the DOM model the way you're suggesting, that would cease to be possible - and then what would be the purpose of the DOM?

Comment: Okay.. but I'd like to believe you based on more than just your abundant reputation score. Could you provide some reference or some justification?

Comment: @ohlec press Ctrl + S

Comment: @ohlec true, that's how modern browsers implement it, for practical purposes. But in theory it must be possible to convert it back to valid HTML markup. Like vlaz says, that will happen if you tell the browser to save the page. You'll see the latest version of the page, not the original (at least in Chrome anyway, I tried it just now). Or if you use the Developer Tools to look at the current elements, you'll see a visual HTML representation of the current DOM tree. If it were possible for DOM elements to have multiple parents, that output would prove to be impossible to render as valid HTML.

Comment: @Vrokipal if you'd like some further reading, I can suggest the link I gave in the question above which describes what the DOM is, the DOM standards at https://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR, and also https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork may be of interest. But as we've pointed out, you can prove the assertion quite simply by thinking about how you could turn a DAG-enabled DOM back into valid HTML - you can't.

Comment: So in conclusion, within the current standards and implementations of HTML, browsers etc, it's not possible to create a DAG structure within the DOM, because it would no longer map to HTML. Everything is predicated on the tree model. In theory it might be possible to re-design the whole concept to accommodate the idea, but that would require a total re-write of the standards, browser rendering engines, tools etc etc etc. I think that's a separate question to the one you've posed here.

Comment: @ohlec maybe it's not strictly a requirement to be able to do that. Neither are Developer Tools (although debugging would be hard if they couldn't render it back to HTML). But the standards currently require that the DOM is a tree. Everything, including the workings of browser rendering engines, are based on that notion. It would be a pretty radical change. And would you have to change HTML to match? Otherwise they're no longer equivalent, which is a pretty fundamental rule to break.

Comment: @ohlec Perhaps https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-LS-20040407/load-save.html is a good one - this is the spec describing how a DOM object must be serialisable both from and to XML (of which HTML is, of course, a specific variety). If it's serialisable to XML, then it must be representable as a hierarchical tree, because that's what XML requires.

Answer (score 1):

No. I have put it to test via following:

```
var testdiv = document.createElement("div");
testdiv.innerHTML="Im testing";
document.body.insertBefore(testdiv,document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

so my testdiv appended to top of the body.
Now when append exact same node to end of body:

```
document.body.append(testdiv);
```

Node is removed from top and appended to bottom.

However, there is a workaround.
Nodes in javascript are objects, therefor you can add additional parameter to them. You can use it to set an ID for each node element, you can store which elements are in which ID in an array.
As a basic example:

```
var map=[];
var testdiv = document.createElement("div");
testdiv.innerHTML="Im testing";
testdiv.myID=1;
if (!map[1]) map[1]=[];
map[1].push(testdiv);

document.body.append(testdiv);

var testdiv2=testdiv.cloneNode(true);
testdiv2.myID=testdiv.myID;
document.body.append(testdiv2);
if (!map[1]) map[1]=[];
map[1].push(testdiv2);
```

Now if you query map for elements, it will return 2 nodes with ID 1. and this map array is connected to those nodes inside DOM. You are able to get ID of nodes in your DOM by looking at their myID.